# Translating a rendering in Greek of a word/term/name in a different language into English

Tags: creative-writing, translation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozymandias

So I was reading this article on Percy Bysshe Shelley's Ozymandias, wondering how the author came up with the name.

It basically says that "Ozymandias" is a rendering in Greek of Ramesses II's throne name.

I thought it would be cool if I could translate a rendering in Greek of a name like "Set" into English, or a name like "Pestilence of livestock", which refers to one of the Biblical plagues that happened in Egypt into English, so I can write a poem about it maybe.

How do you do that? I couldn't find any tool on the Internet that would allow me to do that. I am assuming there's a sort of reference book for these sorts of things.

Comment: There is no specialised tool for translating names, especially not ancient ones. You just do your research, case by case. There's plenty of resources for doing *that*, starting with Wikipedia.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it doesn't fit on Writing.SE and is better suited for a SE about language or translation (not sure which as I'm not familiar with them all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **It Depends**

The first question, in my view, is whether a translation is a good idea. It would seem that "Ozymandias"  is more of a transliteration into English of the Greek name, which in turn seems to be a transliteration and Hellenization of the Egyptian "User-maat-re", which if I am not mistaken indicates a devotion to the god Re (a variant of the sun-god Ra), a concept which is surely not expressed in the English word "Ozymandias". A **translation** might be "Chosen of Re" or some such.

In any given case, was the name in its original usage understood as a description or rather as a pure name. For example "Fletcher" once meant a parson who attached feathers to arrows, and by extension, one who made arrows. Similarly, "Smith" once meant a metal-worker, particularly a worker of Iron. But if, for example,  some novel about modern Americans of 2019 written in another language were to translate a man named "Fletcher" into "arrow-makeer" or "Smith" into "iron-worker"  it would seriously distort how those names are understood in context. Few people meeting a person with one of those names think much on the occupational origins of the names. Many may not even know them. In such a case, translation runs the serious risk of giving a flase impression.

Of course if it is merely a case of wanting an effect, then a name like "One-stone" may be preferable to "Einstein".